# Dart Html: add Event Handlers to objects which yet not exists

Tags: jquery, html, events, dart, live

In jQuery i can add Event Handlers to Elements which yet not exist but are later added via something like this:

```
$(window).on('click', '.record-todo .icon-remove', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

I didn't found anything like that in the Html Library of Dart

Comment: bind a click event to window, then inspect the event target to see what element the event was triggered on. this is how event delegation works behind the scenes. Though, generally this is done using `document`, not `window`.

Comment: i tried that but couldn't figure how to get the target Element from the Event object (feeling really dump now since i searched for about an hour in the API docs)

Comment: Can you provide what you've tried? i'm not familiar with dart so having to find examples of it on my own probably isn't the best way to see what you are doing.

Comment: sure 
`this._contentEl.onClick.listen((MouseEvent event){ event.currentTarget;event.target;});`

currentTarget and target are of type [EventTarget](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/EventTarget.html), where do i get the element from which was clicked on ?!

Comment: Looking at the api docs, i would expect event.target to get what you're looking for... digging more.

Comment: i also thought that, but it was not ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should bind to a click event to body, and then query the `target` properly of the event.  That will yield the element that was the target. Here is a working example. First, the html file:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>
    <p id='text'>This is a para</p>
    <script type="application/dart" src='webscratch.dart'></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the Dart file:

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  document.body.onClick.listen((MouseEvent event){
    window.console.log(event.currentTarget);
    window.console.log(event.target);
    var div = new DivElement();
    div.text = 'New div element content';
    document.body.children.add(div);
  });
}
```

When you first click on the `<p>`, the event target will be a ParagraphElement and the targetEvent will be a BodyElement.  Clicking the `<p>` generates a new div. Clicking on that div makes that the event target.